# How to get browsers recognise visited links on the form <url>#<anchor>

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor, visited

I have a page whith links of the form <url>?<parameters> and some of the form <url>?<parameters>#<anchor>. There are several different of the latter but one example that can easily be understood looks like this (about):

```
<a href="http://www.mu_site.com/forum.php?forum=1&thread=1#p5">My forum #1: Tread 1, go to post 5</a>
```

Now I have these styles attached to the page

```
    .pageContent {
        FONT-SIZE: 8pt;
        COLOR: #666666;
        FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma, sans-serif;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .pageContent A {
        FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: #8d8d8d; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    .pageContent A:hover {
        COLOR: #000000;
    }
    .pageContent A:visited {
        COLOR: #660000;
    }
```

The pageContent style is in use where the links are and everything works almost everywhere.

What puzzles me is that my links of the latter form doesn't get marked as visited. I've experimented with different DOCTYPE settings but I can't get it to work. I've searced the net many times (I've had this problem for more than a year) but either I don't know what to search for or it only happens to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the styles in this order?

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */ <br>
a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */ <br>
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */ <br>
a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */ <br>
```

See reference http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#x35